# Xcode 6 Autolayout- UITableView columns

Tags: swift, autolayout, xcode6

I am trying to us the interface builder in Xcode 6 and auto layout to create a really basic data table with UITableView. It does not seem UITableView has any concept of columns so I created 6 labels in the header section and 6 labels in my cell. How can I align the labels in the cell up with the header labels and make them fill the screen?

Comment: For tabular data you may want to look at `UICollectionView`, or a custom library view. Despite its name, `UITableView` is not meant for dealing with actual tabular multi-column data.

Comment: ah thanks, I think I will actually move away from structuring it that way as I don't often see tables like this in apps. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite it's name, `UITableView` is only meant for one-dimensional (list) data. iOS has a class for 2-dimensional data (`UICollectionView`), and there are many libraries for making more spreadsheet-like views.

Your options are either to use `UICollectionView`, a library, or change the format you display your data in.